# TFS 2017 - Is there a way to create a NET NEW standalone WorkItem (form)?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

My manager has asked me to look into creating a whole new form for TFS - Change Request

I would imagine this is possible, but I really have no idea where to begin building this.

This is not part of the Agile Workflow form set that TFS comes with. It should stand on it's own.

I suppose they may want to integrate this later, so I will have to keep that in mind.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/vsts/reference/add-modify-field?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the "Change Request" you mentioned is a new Work Item Type. So you can follow the instruction here to do this: [Add or modify a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/vsts/reference/add-modify-wit?view=tfs-2018).